# Is it possible to load multiple .dll's using powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have 10 .dll's which has to be loaded, is it possible to do using the powershell? Small snippet on the same is much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by load a DLL? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\folder\file.dll");

Comment: I have few c# files which will be finally converted as a .dll libraries, I need to load all the libraries to the powershell, so researching ways for it

Comment: @navoneel : is it possible to load multiple .dlls with repetitive of same code block?

Comment: use multiple times `Add-Type -Path path\to\dll`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can load them all by doing the following,

```
$dlls = (Get-ChildItem -path "Path to Folder containing .dlls").fullname

foreach ($dll in $dlls)
{
       Add-Type -Path $dll
}
```

Comment: I'd add logic to handle dlls which contain unmanaged code.  We don't know what kind of dll's he's trying to load.